# How to remove records in a dataframe

Tags: r

I need to remove specific rows of my dataframe, but I have troubles doing it. 
The dataset looks like this:

```
> head(mergedmalefemale)
  coupleid gender shop time amount
1        1      W    3    1  29.05
2        1      W    1    2  31.65
3        1      W    3    3     NA
4        1      W    2    4  17.75
5        1      W    3    5 -28.40
6        2      W    1    1  42.30
```

What I would like to do is deleting all the records of a coupleid where at least one amount is NA or negative. In the example above, all rows with coupleid "1" should be deleted as there are rows with negative values and NA's. 
I tried it with functions like `na.omit(mergedmalefemale)` etc. but this deletes only the rows with NA's but not other rows with the same cupleid. As I am a beginner I'd be happy if someone could help me.

Comment: In future provide some code we can cut and paste to generate sample data. Makes our lives easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do not want to only omit the amounts that are NA or negative, but want to omit all data with the same id, you have to first find the id's you want to remove and then remove them.

```
mergedmalefemale <- read.table(text="
    coupleid gender shop time amount
    1        1      W    3    1  29.05
    2        1      W    1    2  31.65
    3        1      W    3    3     NA
    4        1      W    2    4  17.75
    5        1      W    3    5 -28.40
    6        2      W    1    1  42.30", 
    header=TRUE)

# Find NA and negative amounts
del <- is.na(mergedmalefemale[,"amount"]) | mergedmalefemale[,"amount"]<0
# Find coupleid with NA or negative amounts
ids <- unique(mergedmalefemale[del,"coupleid"])
# Remove data with coupleid such that amount is NA or negative
mergedmalefemale[!mergedmalefemale[,"coupleid"] %in% ids,]
```

Comment: Assuming that for a beginner multiple subsetting can be a bit confusing (it was for me), note that you could also use subset() instead of the last line:
`subset(mergedmalefemale, ! coupleid  %in% ids)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one alternative. Consider your data.frame is called `df`

```
> na.omit(df[ rowSums(df[, sapply(df, is.numeric)]< 0, na.rm=TRUE)  ==0, ])
  coupleid gender shop time amount
1        1      W    3    1  29.05
2        1      W    1    2  31.65
4        1      W    2    4  17.75
6        2      W    1    1  42.30
```

Answer (score 1):

Another good opportunity to apply `data.table`

```
require(data.table)
mergedmalefemale <- as.data.table(mergedmalefemale)
mergedmalefemale[, if(!any(is.na(amount) | amount < 0)) .SD, by=coupleid]

#   coupleid gender shop time amount
#1:        2      W    1    1   42.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly dirty way

```
# identify the coupleids that need to stay/be removed
agg <- aggregate(amount ~ coupleid, data=mergedmalefemale, FUN=function(x) min(is.na(x)|(x>0)))

# insert a column alongside "amount.y" that puts a 0 next to rows to be deleted
df.1 <- merge(mergedmalefemale, agg, by="coupleid")

# delete the rows
df.1 <- df.1[df.1$amount.y == 1, ]
```